# XPath: Search for HTML element within HTML element

Tags: xpath

With XPath, how would you search for elements that only contain another specific element? For example, what expression would result in getting all `<p>` tags that contain `<strong>` elements within them?

```
<p>This is some text that <strong>contains another HTML element</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XPath you use square brackets to filter. It is called the predicate. See I.e. [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_predicate.htm) .

To select all p’s with a element strong you use

```
 //p[strong]
```

If you want to find all p’s with only the element strong and no other elements, you add

```
//p[strong][count(*)=count(strong)]
```

The `*` stands for any element.

If, as in your example , you only interested in p’s with the strong element being the last child node you use

```
//p[strong[not(following-sibling::node())]]
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1).  And if containing a `strong` element should include descendants beyond children, use `//p[.//strong]`.

Answer (score 3):

Predicates are the way to go.

> what expression would result in getting all p tags that contain  elements within them?

If you only want to select `p` elements with direct `strong` children, you can use `p[strong]`, if you're looking for any descendants, use `p[descendant::strong]`. In both cases the context node has to be at the level of the `p` elements.

Comment: Good too (+1), and I see you already had descendants covered.